# Declaring a variable in a public function (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few Public functions that are called on in order in another function... Something like this:

```
Public Sub func1()
  Operation 1
End Sub

Public Sub func2()
  Operation 2
End Sub

Public Sub func3()
  Operation 3
End Sub

Sub Execute()
  Call func1()
  Call func2()
  Call func3()
End Sub
```

What I would like to understand is if there is a common variable that I am declaring in each of these functions, something like this:

```
Dim LastRow as Long
LastRow = Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row
```

Is it safe to assume that I can declare it once in `func1()` and use it in both `func2()` and `func3()`?

Or I have to declare it 3x times in each of these functions?

Thanks

Comment: You could declare once globally or 3 times locally or declare in first and pass as argument to later. Really depends on what you are doing with this variable. Also, drop the Call keyword. Not needed.

Comment: Can you please give me an example how you declare globally? and an example on how to declare on first and pass as argument later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is with a global variable, where you assign in `func1` (though I would change these names as they are subs). Note the public variable is declared at the top of the module outside of the subs. I have changed the name of one sub to `my_Execute`, as `Execute` reminds me too much of a key word in several programming languages.

```
Option Explicit
Public a As Long

Public Sub func1()
    a = 1
End Sub

Public Sub func2()
    MsgBox a
End Sub

Public Sub func3()
    MsgBox a    
End Sub

Public Sub my_Execute()
    func1
    func2
    func3
End Sub
```

---

Declaring once locally and passing through all as an argument by value (ByVal). Note: Here it is declared locally in `my_Execute`, and then passed as an argument to the other subs.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub func1(ByVal a As Long)
   MsgBox "func1 " & a
End Sub

Public Sub func2(ByVal a As Long)
    MsgBox "func2 " & a
End Sub

Public Sub func3(ByVal a As Long)
    MsgBox "func3 " & a
End Sub

Public Sub my_Execute()
    Dim a As Long
    a = 1
    func1 a
    func2 a
    func3 a
End Sub
```

---

Passing `ByRef` so can alter `a` en route:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub func1(ByRef a As Long)
   a = a + 1
End Sub

Public Sub func2(ByRef a As Long)
    a = a + 2
End Sub

Public Sub func3(ByRef a As Long)
     a = a + 3
End Sub

Public Sub my_Execute()
    Dim a As Long
    a = 1
    func1 a
    func2 a
    func3 a
    MsgBox a
End Sub
```

---

Information on ByRef and ByVal [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx)

Comment: If you need further explanation/clarification, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks - I think the first method (global var) is most efficient and elegant. What do you think?

Comment: It really depends what you are going to do with the variable.  Have a read of the following: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx